# Does PosgreSQL Timescale LOFC allows us to specify an ordering?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

Is there a way to fill the missing values in a gap fill, using future observations instead of past ones? This could be achieved if `locf` allowed us to specify an ordering, which I think is not possible.
What we want, is to make `locf` (Last Observation Carried Forward) work like a hypothetical “Next Observation Carried Backward” function.

Comment: Please provide a link to what you are talking about.  Postgresql does not come with a built in `locf` function.

Comment: I'm talking about timescale. Sorry I didn't mention it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer from a TImeScale expert:
*At the moment, there is no direct way to do this. If you don't need to do it in a Continuous Aggregate, there could be opportunities to get the buckets through an outer query, and then return your own future values on a LATERAL join per bucket or a similar technique.*